# Laravel 5.7 - Missing files in composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I´m trying to setup a fresh install of Laravel with Laradock. Actually, a strange thing happens: An empty page shows in the browser and nginx shows up this error in my console...

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/vendor/composer/../../tests/Database/stubs/MigrationCreatorFakeMigration.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /var/www/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost,
>   request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.19.0.6:9000",
>   host: "-> THE HOST <-"

I can find any reference of this missing file, neither on the Laravel repo.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance (:

Comment: `composer update` run this command

Comment: Not working. I even created a file with that name in that path but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

remove folder **vendor** then run commands below:

```
$ composer install
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan optimize
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php artisan route:cache
$ php artisan view:clear
$ php artisan config:cache
$ php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: artisan optimize was removed in 5.6. See https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-removes-artisan-optimize